# Is it possible to dynamically create an array with objects inside?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, object

I am not sure if it is possible but maybe somebody could give some advice.

I have an array of objects:

```
var testArray = [{'name':'name1', 'xaxis':'xaxis1', 'yaxis':'yaxis1'}, 
                 {'name':'name2', 'xaxis':'xaxis2', 'yaxis':'yaxis2'}];
```

The lenght of the array can be different but the keys are always the same.

I have to loop through it in order to get such result:

```
var resultArray = [
                   trace1 = {title: 'name1', x: 'xaxis1', y: 'yaxis1'},
                   trace2 = {title: 'name2', x: 'xaxis2', y: 'yaxis2'},
                   ];
```

I have started by generating var names for JSON objects:

```
for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; ++i) {
    resultArray[i] = 'trace' + i;
}
```

But how to combine it with generating JSON objects I have no idea

Comment: `var resultArray = [ trace1 = ... ]` is not a valid syntax, did you mean `var resultArray = { trace1: ... }` ?

Comment: Actually, I have to generate it like objects assigned to variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your answer `trace1 =` is incorrect json .

I am not sure if you want the trace1, trace2 as names or it in an array. but this would create what you want in a loop:

```
var testArray = [{'name':'name1', 'xaxis':'xaxis1', 'yaxis':'yaxis1'}, 
                 {'name':'name2', 'xaxis':'xaxis2', 'yaxis':'yaxis2'}];
                 
var resultArray = [];
                   
for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; ++i) {
    resultArray['trace' + (i+1)] = { title: testArray[i].name, x: testArray[i].xaxis, y: testArray[i].yaxis };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can chain you Array of object declaration with the `map` helper like this.

```
let id=0;
const coordinatesArray = [
  {
    'name': 'name1',
    'xaxis': 'xaxis1',
    'yaxis': 'yaxis1'
  },
  {
    'name': 'name2',
    'xaxis': 'xaxis2',
    'yaxis': 'yaxis2'
  }
].map(item => ({
  [`trace${++id}`]: {
    title: item.name,
    x: item.xaxis,
    y: item.yaxis
  }
}))

console.log(resultArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()`:

```js
const testArray = [{
    'name': 'name1',
    'xaxis': 'xaxis1',
    'yaxis': 'yaxis1'
  },
  {
    'name': 'name2',
    'xaxis': 'xaxis2',
    'yaxis': 'yaxis2'
  }
];

const resultArray = testArray.map((el, idx) => ({
  [`trace${idx + 1}`]: {
    title: el.name,
    x: el.xaxis,
    y: el.yaxis
  }
}))

console.log(resultArray)
```